# How to change icon in .exe (App Wxwidgets with C++)

Tags: c++, icons, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have build an app with Code::Block, C++ and wxWidgets. I have changed icon for frame successfully, but icon of `.exe` file is still there default.

[image: Image 01]

[image: Image 02]

how to change icon of .exe file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `.rc` file (i.e. `resource.rc`) and set your icon where you find `aaaa ICON`.